# Django Admin Debounce

Tags: jquery, django, django-admin, debouncing

I am using [Python Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/) with as little as possible custom templates and javascript code.

Is there a way to [debounce](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce) click on specific button (or form submit)?

E.g. if user clicks two times (in a short period of time) on the save button, only one call should be made.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any custom templates or javascript, one way to do it would be to rate-limit whatever view, that button is going to send a request to. For example, the 'save' button will send a request to the `change_view` view, so you could put a rate limiter on this. Something like this should work:

```
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit

class YourAdminClass(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @ratelimit(key='ip', rate='1/s')
    def change_view(elf, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # anything else you want to do
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

And this will allow a maximum of 1 per second for any given IP address. Note you will need to install [Django Ratelimit](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Also, note I've never used this personally, it was just the first library that came up when I googled.

#### However...

Why do you need this particular feature. The Django admin interface should never be used as a customer facing site. The only people using it should be people within your company / the company who you're making the site for / yourself. IMO, it should only really be used by other developers, but maybe this isn't the case in all contexts, and maybe it's not the case in your context. Given all of this, ask yourself if it's a feature you really need.

Comment: Context: It's used inside of the company. It was ~5 people in the beginning. Now, it's 100+.
Some or the actions they make in inside admin tool will send notifications/mails/sms to the user with unique tokens etc. Some of the company users are doing double-clicks instead of clicks on the buttons. Alternative is to fix the notifications-related-code... but as usual, we need fast solution.

Comment: ah, I see. Yes, not really ideal. Does the above work?

Comment: Tim, tbh I haven't tried.

I tried something else. I created decorator: https://gist.github.com/adnansinanovic/03d424fb1a160d8774ca1b24b80d521d

And used it as like: 
  @DebounceSaveModel(300)
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

But I wasn't happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not ideal (I hate it), but it works.

I had to write some JS code. Fortunately django admin template was already extended so I had to put one line inside it:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static "admin/js/debounce_form.js" %}"></script>
```

debounce_form.js looks like this:

```
(function ($) {
function debounce(wait) {
  const STATUS_PENDING = 1;
  const STATUS_DONE = 2;

  return {
    status: STATUS_PENDING,
    timeout: null,
    isDone: function(){
      return this.state === STATUS_DONE;
    },
    reset: function() {
      this.status = STATUS_PENDING;
    },
    execute: function(target) {
      args = this;

      var later = function() {
        args.timeout = null;
        args.status = STATUS_DONE;
        target.submit();
      };

      args.status = STATUS_PENDING;
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      args.timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    }
  }
}

var submit = debounce(250);

$( "form" ).submit(function( e ) {
  // debounce multiple form submission
  if (submit.isDone() === false) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    submit.execute(e.target);
    return;
  }

  submit.reset();
});
```

})(django.jQuery);